# Trying to multiply columns but can't get the different ones to add when grouping in mySQL

Tags: mysql, group-by

```
select eventcode, count(eventcode) * price, min(showdate), max(showdate), price
from ticket
group by price;
```

[image]

Please look at the image for better context but I am trying to return the total cost for each eventcode in my query. But when I group by eventcode it doesn't include the different prices that can occur and only returns the first one that it finds. Grouping by price shows the different values that I would like to return together. For example for eventcode 801 I would like to return the total price sum of the 1240 + 2844 + 9850. This is for an assignment and I just can't seem to figure it out. I tried grouping by the count(eventcode) * price but I get an error for invalid use of group function. Sorry for the badly worded question I am just frustrated. Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0):

If you want the total price for each *eventcode*, then that should be in the `group by`:

```
select eventcode, sum(price), min(showdate), max(showdate)
from ticket
group by eventcode;
```

Notes:

- This returns one row per `eventcode`.  That is how `group by` works.
- You want the total price, so that is `sum(price)`.
- You don't want any columns in the `select` that are not in the `group by` and not arguments to aggregation functions.  Hence, no `, price`.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to help!! I think I asked the question poorly. I was grouping by price to show that for every eventcode there are multiple prices that I can figure out to have each one multiplied by the number of tickets sold at that price and then added for the total per eventcode. I would like to group by eventcode but I need to return the total for each one even with the different prices if that makes sense. Thanks again for all your help!

Comment: @Arthur . . . I think the above does what you want.  If you have a `quantity` column, then you might want `sum(quantity * price)`.